# Identify file name(s) associated with chkdsk corrupt file record segments

Tags: windows, windows-10, hard-drive, chkdsk

I have a Dell XPS15, 32 GB RAM, 1 TB SSD, Windows 10.

The following are the results from CHKDSK read-only:

```
The type of the file system is NTFS.
Volume label is OS.

WARNING!  /F parameter not specified.
Running CHKDSK in read-only mode.

Stage 1: Examining basic file system structure ...
Progress: 0 of 516096 done; Stage:  0%; Total:  0%; ETA:   0:24:50
Progress: 27291 of 516096 done; Stage:  5%; Total:  2%; ETA:   0:24:19 .
Progress: 59292 of 516096 done; Stage: 11%; Total:  4%; ETA:   0:23:39 ..
Attribute record (80, "") from file record segment 1003F
is corrupt.
Progress: 107648 of 516096 done; Stage: 20%; Total:  8%; ETA:   0:00:15 ...
Progress: 137486 of 516096 done; Stage: 26%; Total: 10%; ETA:   0:00:15
Progress: 192769 of 516096 done; Stage: 37%; Total: 14%; ETA:   0:00:14 .
Progress: 253613 of 516096 done; Stage: 49%; Total: 18%; ETA:   0:00:12 ..
Progress: 253614 of 516096 done; Stage: 49%; Total: 18%; ETA:   0:00:12 ...
Progress: 311809 of 516096 done; Stage: 60%; Total: 22%; ETA:   0:00:12
Progress: 366821 of 516096 done; Stage: 71%; Total: 26%; ETA:   0:00:11 .
Progress: 421121 of 516096 done; Stage: 81%; Total: 29%; ETA:   0:00:11 ..
Progress: 475047 of 516096 done; Stage: 92%; Total: 32%; ETA:   0:00:11 ...

The total allocated size in attribute record (80, "")
of file A00000007ADAE is incorrect.

Deleted corrupt attribute list entry
with type code 80 in file 7ADAE.

Attribute record (80, "") from file record segment 21D8F
is corrupt.

Attribute record (80, "") from file record segment 74337
is corrupt.

Attribute record (80, "") from file record segment 74CF5
is corrupt.

Progress: 516096 of 516096 done; Stage: 100%; Total: 35%; ETA:   0:00:09


  516096 file records processed.

File verification completed.

File record segment 21D8F is an orphan.
File record segment 74337 is an orphan.
File record segment 74CF5 is an orphan.
Progress: 16440 of 16440 done; Stage: 100%; Total: 26%; ETA:   0:00:14 .

  16440 large file records processed.

Errors found.  CHKDSK cannot continue in read-only mode.
```

Since it cannot continue, does that imply that there may be additional existing errors?

My understanding is that `CHKDSK /R` will recover 'READABLE' information.
So, before I run `chkdsk /r`, is there any way to identify the filename(s) associated with:

- file 7ADAE
- file record segment 1003F
- file record segment 21D8F
- file record segment 74337
- file record segment 74CF5

Once I identify the filenames I plan on restoring them from a recent backup after running
`chkdsk /r.

Comment: Not as far as I know.

Comment: If you run `chkdsk /r`, it might actually tell you the filenames as it recovers them.  Sadly there's no "dry run" mode, although of course you can do a block-level clone of the disk and try running whatever tool you like on the clone.